# Continue interrupted download of downthemall? (403 error)

Tags: firefox, download, iso-image, download-manager

I was downloading an ISO file of WINDOWS 10 to create an upgrade disk in windows 7 using a simple trick at : http://techdows.com/2015/08/use-this-trick-to-get-windows-10-iso-direct-download-links.html

But link was valid till 24hr and download was not completed. Can I continue it?? If I restart the download ,it will again just download and download and time up. I've tried trick of http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?p=6333845 . It was working when i was using Firefox's built in downloader. But not in "Downthemall". Now when 24 hrs have passed it says 403 error. Please how can I continue??

Answer (score 0):

#### How to download official Windows 10 ISO files

> If you need to install or reinstall Windows 10, you can use the tools
>   on this page to create your own installation media using either a USB
>   flash drive or a DVD.
>
> **Before you begin**
>
> - Make sure you have:
>
>   - An internet connection (internet service provider fees may apply).
>   - Sufficient data storage available on a computer, USB or external drive for the download.
>   - A blank USB or DVD (and DVD burner) with at least 4 GB of space if you want to create media. We recommend using a blank USB or
>       blank DVD, because any content on it will be deleted.
> - [Read the System Requirements](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-10-specifications).
> - If you will be installing the operating system for the first time, you will need your Windows product key
>     (xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx). For more information about product
>     keys and when they are required, visit the [FAQ](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/faq) page.
> - For Enterprise editions please visit the [Volume Licensing Service Center](https://www.microsoft.com/licensing/servicecenter/default.aspx).
>
> Use the media creation tool to download Windows. This tool provides
>   the best download experience for customers running Windows 7, 8.1 and
>   10. To learn how to use the tool, go to the Installing Windows 10 using the media creation tool page. Tool includes:
>
> - File formats optimized for download speed.
> - Built in media creation options for USBs and DVDs.
>      Optional conversion to ISO file format.
>
> [Download Tool Now (32-bit version)](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=616935)
>
> [Download Tool Now (64-bit version)](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=616936)

The reet of the article explains how to use the Media Creation Tool and includes screenshots.

Source [How to download official Windows 10 ISO files](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wiki/windows_10-windows_install/how-to-download-official-windows-10-iso-files/35cde7ec-5b6f-481c-a02d-dadf465df326)

Comment: I donot wanted to try Media creation tool. But I downloaded it and it said your pc needs to restart and i restarted and same. But once I clicked it twice & one window said pc needs to restart and other worked. What was that?

Comment: Well if you run firefox in compatibility mode for xp sp3 it would download those files and you may use IDM or downthemall.